# How to avoid messy git commits in a PR

Tags: git, github

I've learned enough git to basically get by and I'd like to understand what has caused all these commits in what was intended to be a 3 commit PR.  (I know I could adopt a better workflow to reduce the 3 commits down to 1, but for this question, let's set that aside.)

Here's the process I went through in starting work on a fork of the bioconda-recipes project.

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
git checkout -b mybranch
```

I then implement my changes (and entered 3 commits).  When I submitted the PR however, there were a bunch of merge commits from back in September (I did all my current work just recently in December).  I don't recall what I did back in September.  I probably worked on a different branch that also resulted in a PR.  The changes shown in the diff of the PR reflected only the changes I did recently.  I don't know what caused all these merges to show up in the commit history and I'd like to know what caused them.  Were they just a bunch of `git pull upstream master` calls back in September?  Why do all of these show up in the PR?:

[image]

Alternatively, is there something I should do to start clean with 0 commits, like `git rebase` or `git revert` on the upstream master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to rebase your branch onto **`upstream/master`**, in order to ensure a PR which will include only your three new commits:

```
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git switch mybranch
git rebase --onto upstream/master master mybranch
git push --force
```

The idea is to make a PR from the most recent state of the original repository ("`upstream`"), not from your fork ("`origin`").

Check the state of your PR then (after pushing the new history of `mybranch`)

For the next PR, simply start it from `upstream/master` to be sure to include only your new PR commits.

Comment: The PR was already merged. I'm looking for how to avoid that situation next time, not how to fix it after the fact. Am I understanding your suggestion (that it's a fix) correctly? If so, and I just want to avoid the issue next time, should I do `git fetch upstream; git rebase upstream/master master; git checkout -b mybranch` when I want to start work on a new issue - or would I need to do what you suggest anyway to incorporate new changes before I submit a PR?

Comment: @hepcat72 Yes: to avoid it next time, make sure to start your new PR from `upstream/master`.